# Are "whores" and "horse" homophones?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics, homophones

I’m Spanish but sometimes see TV shows in English.

My question is whether the words *horse* and *whores* sound exactly the same, because in many English language TV shows it seems like they are, which really surprises me.

Are they homophones?

I cannot hear any voicing at the end of the word *whores* to distinguish the two words.

Comment: You'll get a similarity between "whores" and "horse" in *some* accents (I'm tempted to say southern US maybe?), but definitely not all.

Comment: I'm now hearing 'get off your horse and drink your milk' in a worrying new light.

Comment: On the matter of hearing the vowel sounds: there's a Sondheim song (from A little Night Music) which came to mind when I read this debate:
"He talks softly of his wars
And his horses and his whores ..."
Most UK English speakers, and I presume (given it's Sondheim) most US ones, would recognise a rhyme between "whores" and "wars". They would find a rhyme between "horse" and "wars" much more of a stretch.

Comment: Well, rhyming is based on both vowels and consonants, so this evidence doesn't indicate which part is different.

Comment: [Obligatory Cyanide and Happiness cartoon](http://www.lowbird.com/user/deathpak/view/2008/11/explosm-comictrojanhorse5) in this context.

Comment: To add to the confusion, Oars sounds very similar to both words as well, especially depending on the speaker's accent.

Comment: What about whores and hoarse?

Comment: There was a joke about this in "the big bang theory", where the indian guy says "the only way to feel better about Penny going out with other guys is to get back on the whores". Other guys correct him "the phrase is get back on the horse" to which he responds "that's discusting, dude!" You can recognize the difference with longer o and the ending z [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jobvVaekOKA)

Comment: While technically not homophones, they will sound almost identical in some situations. In some accents they will sound identical in some the only difference will be the W and H, in others the s or z sound (from @Araucaria's answer).  Mostly you can tell by context. May whores or one horse. One whore or many horses. You should only really get in trouble with many whores and one horse. But, thankfully those  situations don't come up much.

Comment: The highest upvoted answer is talking about a very subtle difference. They sound *almost* the same.

Comment: @aslum To add some anecdote to this: Last time I (German speaker, so neither native English speaker nor having any knowledge of the subject discussed) was in India, a local tried to explain to me (in English) some basic facts about an ongoing cricket tournament. In particular, he explained that a game's duration was so-and-so many (horse?whores?oars?). Totally confused, I asked back "hours?" - "No, no. Not oars, it's oars". I swear I couldn't hear any difference between the two words and left it at that. It wasn't until I found a written description that cricket games are divided into *overs*.

Comment: Relevant: http://www.engrish.com/2016/04/sick-of-all-these-whores-tramping-around/

Comment: Compare https://translate.google.com/?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob#en/en/horse to https://translate.google.com/?ie=UTF-8&client=tw-ob#en/en/whores (click on the speaker symbol in the bottom of the textbox). I would also like to add that you probably wouldn't be able to hear the difference when a non-native speakers pronounces one of these words.

Comment: Reminds of the amusing "mishead lyric" in Simon and Garfunkel's "The Boxer":

Asking only workman's wages
I come looking for a job
But I get no offers
Just a come-on from the horse on Seventh Avenue

Comment: Using the IPA, horse uses [s], and whores uses [z].  When I lived in Mexico, I noticed that [z] was not pronounced in my region.

Comment: Has a song or poem in English rhymed `horse` and `wars`?  Skimming a few online rhyming dictionaries [1](http://www.poetrysoup.com/what_rhymes_with/wars),[2](http://www.rhymer.com/RhymingDictionary/horse.html) suggests not.

Comment: @Pickett There is no phonemic /z/ in Spanish, but quite possibly the phonetic allophone [z] was used in your region of Mexico. This is because [when immediately followed by a voiced consonant, the sound produced by the letter *s* becomes voiced in Spanish via regressive assimilation, as in the common words *mismo, desde, musgo*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripción_fonética_del_español_con_el_AFI#cite_note-s-11), so /ˈmusgo/ is said  [ˈmusɣ̞o̞]~[ˈmuz̺ɣ̞o̞]~[ˈmuz̻ɣ̞o̞]. This is not phonemic; native speakers do it naturally but it doesn’t change “which word” they hear.

Comment: @Pickett Note also that our asker is from Bilbao in the Basque Country, which means he actually does pronounce words written with a *z* in them differently than you wlll have heard these pronounced in Mexico. However, this is not a distinction between /s/ and /z/ but rather one of /s/ and /θ/. Mexico is a [seseo region](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seseo) but most of Spain is not, especially in Bilbao. Many Spaniards pronounce [*juzgar*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcripción_fonética_del_español_con_el_AFI#cite_note-c.2Fz-10) as [χuðˈɣ̞a̠ɾ]—not [xuzˈɰa̠ɾ] like your Mexican friends may.

Comment: @Hagen: many Indians pronounce /v/s like /w/s. And not having any /w/s in German, it may be hard for you to distinguish *owers* from *oars*.

Answer (score 426, accepted):

In most varieties of English, these two words are not homophones. But there is an interesting story about why this is so.

In English the alveolar fricatives /s/ and /z/ are contrastive. Notionally, the first is unvoiced and the second voiced. So we can find minimal pairs of words where the difference in voicing results in a change of meaning:

- /su:/
- /zu:/

The first word here is the word *sue* or *Sue*, the second is the word *zoo*.

In a language like Spanish, there is only one alveolar fricative, /s/. This is usually voiceless (although it can become voiced in certain environments). However because there is no phoneme /z/ in Spanish, if a speaker uses a [z] instead of an [s] in a word, it will still be recognised as the same word. So, for example, English speakers of Spanish may well use a [z] in all sorts of words where a Spanish speaker would use an [s], but it will always be recognised as the Spanish phoneme /s/. In other words a Spanish speaker will always map both an [s] and a [z] sound onto the Spanish phoneme /s/.

Because of this lack of contrast in Spanish, it is often difficult for Spanish speakers to differentiate between /s/ and /z/ when listening to English.

Now, many English speakers will tell you that the sound at the end of the word *whores* is voiced. In actual fact, if it is not followed by a word beginning with a voiced sound, then the /z/ at the end of the word *whores* will be at least partially, and quite probably completely devoiced. We would show this in a narrow transcription by putting a little circle as a diacritic under the z:

- [hɔ:z̥]

  <sup>British English transcription</sup>

A native English speaker will swear blind—I predict at least ten comments under this post saying exactly this—that they can hear the voicing in the sound at the end of the word *whores* when spoken naturally. However, if you cut that devoiced /z/ off the end of the word and play it back to them without the rest of the word they will confidently tell you that it's an /s/.

Here is what is really happening when a native speaker hears the word *whores* and why they can differentiate it from the word *horse*. Unvoiced consonants have an effect on preceding vowels, whereby they cause them to become much shorter. This effect is known as prefortis clipping. If you say the word *bead* and then the word *beat* you should be able to hear that the vowel in the word *beat* is much shorter than the vowel in the word *bead*. [Try it at home!] It is the unclipped, and therefore relatively long vowel in the word *bead* that tells your language brain that the phoneme at the end is a 'voiced' /d/ and not an unvoiced /t/. Your brain will trick you into thinking that the sound at the end of the word *bead* is voiced, but this is just because of the length of the vowel.

So, if a Spanish speaker listening to the word *whores* and *horse* puts all their concentration into listening to whether they can hear any voicing in the fricative at the ends of these words, they will not be able to detect any. However, if they concentrate on the contrasting lengths of the vowels, they will notice that the vowel in *horse* is much shorter than the vowel in *whores*. This is actually what leads English speakers to hear the difference  between the two words.

The story above is true for both standard British and American English (both words will have an /r/ of course in most varieties of American English). However, there may well be varieties of English which use different vowels in each of these two items.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44398/discussion-on-answer-by-araucaria-are-whores-and-horse-homophones).

Answer (score 12):

Although the phonetic transcription in a dictionary may be the same, I do hear a difference in most native accents.

- Start: I'd say the **H** in Horse is a bit stronger than the **WH**
- Middle: I'd say the O in horse is more of an oe and shorter than in
  whore.

You would probably hear more difference in some accents than others, though. 
My2¢

EDIT. This comment by @tchrist explained it far better, in a more technical way:

> The voiced /z/ of the WH- word triggers a longer /o/vowel via
>   regressive assimilation, which triggers more pronounced rounding of
>   that /o/, which in turn triggers greater rounding of the initial
>   consonant than occurs in the H- word, again via regressive
>   assimilation

Comment: I'm very skeptical that there's any measurable difference between the initial consonants of "horse" and "whores." I think that part should only be included in your answer if you have some kind of supporting evidence.

Comment: I make clear in my answer that it is only my perception. I state it as an opinion and not as a fact. The fact is than the dictionary says they are alike, that is my unsupporting evidence, but I do hear differences, as others have stated above too. You should not vote down an opinion defined as an opinion just because you don't agree with it. You should comment on it but not vote it down. 
Or is it only because I have a Spanish name?

Comment: @sumelic The voiced /z/ of the WH- word triggers a longer /o/vowel via regressive assimilation, which triggers more pronounced rounding of  that /o/, which in turn triggers greater rounding of the initial consonant than occurs in the H- word, again via regressive assimilation  This is what the poster is noticing.

Comment: @tchrist: Does that happen? I'd be interested in learning if the voicing of the final consonant actually has such far-reaching effects. I had no idea of any of those details from this post. I also would not have been able to interpret "a bit stronger" as meaning "less rounded."

Comment: @sumelic In my own experience, the poster is correct, as per the explanation provided by tchrist.  Santi, you might want to edit some version of his comment into your answer to make it stronger.

Comment: If you listen to Danny Devito say "whores" in It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia, you can definitely hear a difference between the h in horse and the wh in whores. Although my perception of that is certainly influenced by the following vowel difference as well. It's a bit like the way some people in the southern US pronounce wh words.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the excellent points made above, one interesting example of how pronunciation shifts over time is that "whore" and "hour" [were homophones in Shakespeare's day](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/theatre/william-shakespeare/10372964/Shakespeare-read-in-Elizabethan-accent-reveals-puns-jokes-and-rhymes.html), which casts a rather different light on [this passage from *As You Like It*](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/asyoulikeit/asyoulikeit.2.7.html):

> And then he drew a dial from his poke,
>       And, looking on it with lack-lustre eye,
>       Says very wisely, 'It is ten o'clock:
>       Thus we may see,' quoth he, 'how the world wags:
>       'Tis but an hour ago since it was nine,
>       And after one hour more 'twill be eleven;
>       And so, from hour to hour, we ripe and ripe,
>       And then, from hour to hour, we rot and rot;
>       And thereby hangs a tale.

Comment: Actually, I suspect "whore" had an /h/, while "hour" didn't. But quite possibly the /h/ was dropped in some accents in "an hour", "one hour", "from hour" (if it wasn't dropped entirely).

Comment: There was a joke I remember from my childhood (maybe 45 years ago) which ended in the punchline of "there's nae trains for twa hours" - said by an Aberdonian station-master to two ladies of the night. It didn't occur to me as strange at the time but in hindsight it relies on the pronunciation of 'hours' with the initial 'h' not being silent. So I suspect that at least in the past, Scottish pronunciation of hours was similar to the Shakespearean pronunciation referenced above. (Of course you are all aware that the Scottish pronunciation of 'whores' is somewhere between 'hoors' and 'hoo-ers'...)

Answer (score 5):

The forms 'whores' and 'horse' are not homophones in a standard (English/American/Australian) dialect and etymologically speaking the 'w' is a late (C15/16) spurious addition so should not make any difference to pronunciation. However, children learning a rare and archaic word from books/reading may pronounce as 'wars' or transfer stronger rounding from the functional wh* (pronoun/adjective interrogative/relative words - esp. 'who' which originally have a hw* or earlier kw* or qu* type origin). See e.g. etymonline.com under 'whore' and 'wh-'.

The big difference is the longer long 'o' in 'whore' versus the shorter long 'o' in 'horse'. While in both cases the 'o' is long, it is shorter before 's' (or an unvoiced stop) and longer still due to the prevocalized plural /s/ or [zs] (say 'horses' aloud and you should hear your voicing pulse on and off again like [szs]).

Thus the second subtler difference is the (pre)voiced plural morph /s/ = [z] or [zs] in 'whores' (bleeding but diminishing voicing) versus /s's/ = [s's] or [szs] in 'horses'.

As tchrist points out in a comment on another post, the lengthening of the vowel tends to allow stronger rounding and thus licenses the lead 'w' or 'whore' (backward assimilation). Similarly the vowel is more open/lower (bottom lip and jaw drop more). I see these phenomena as deriving from more time to pronounce the word including more time to produce the rounding and height features of the vowel, starting during the preceding consonant.

The plural morpheme takes on the unvoiced form [s] only after an unvoiced consonant, including when doubled as an extra syllable in 'horses' where there is actually no vowel corresponding to the 'e'. The 's' in both 'horse' and 'horses' is unvoiced, so [s] not [z].

Note that quotes as 's' represent what is written ('orthography'), slash bracketing represents conventional (phonemic or morphemic) base representation corresponding to what people think they are saying: /s/ by convention used for the plural morpheme though phonemically arguably /z/ is more appropriate, before any phonetic variation (free variation or coarticulation related to context that changes the phonetic form/morph), while square brackets represent more accurately what is actually pronounced: [z] is the plural morph after vowels or voiced consonants, and [s] is the plural morph with voicing lost after unvoiced consonants similar to the usual pronuncation of the phoneme /s/ in general, including when syllabic ('rose' involves /z/ not /s/ --> [z] with 'roses' as [z'z] versus 'horses' which is /s/ --> [s] and [s's].

Here ['z] and ['s] and ['n] etc. indicate a syllabic form often conventionally replaced by a schwa (rotated e for a minimal vowel representing voicing punctuating but nor interrupting the [szs]) and correctly written with the prime symbol underneath the consonant (not sure I could insert the unicode here).

Comment: By "long 'o'" are you talking about phonetic, allophonic length like Araucaria? That seems most likely to me, but I wasn't quite sure, since some people use "long o" to refer to the vowel of "goat" and "short o" to refer to the vowel of "lot." Also, I think it's possible this could cause confusion for future readers aside from me.

Comment: @sumelic yes and no - yes it is phonetic and hence technically an allophone, but I regard length as a phonemic feature in 'horse' as indicated by the 'r' (as in 'hoar'), and am here ignoring the stronger allophonic diphthong feature of shifting to a schwa or higher transition into the sibilant as the jaw moves up.

Comment: I've tried to clarify by editing the answer: it is phonemically a long vowel in both words, but shorter before [s] or [t] in 'horse' or 'horse to water' or 'horticulture' or 'whore to culture' (these two can reduce to sound the same) and longer before the /s/ or /z/ plural morph which includes a prevoicing component in the allophone used after vowels, diphthongs and voice consonants, thus making a longer allophone in 'whores' and a shorter allophone in 'horse' of what is in both cases phonemically a long vowel.

Answer (score 5):

The words aren't homophones in Boston because we pronounce "horse" as "hoss," and sometimes "whores" is pronounced "hoes." So you see, we Bostonians can easily distinguish between "whores" and "horse" -- and verbally too. *Hahaha*
Not, I hasten to add, that we have either in Boston.

---

Here is an American voice pronouncing "whores, horrors, horse, and hours" back to back. I think it might be interesting to play the video for a couple of people who can't see it, to find out if they can hear the difference.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3JZLV9IpK0 
(around 2.5)

---

I saw chalked on the sidewalk outside an elementary school:

"Susan is a hour."