# Are Greenpeace and green peas pronounced the same?

Tags: pronunciation

Are Greenpeace and green peas pronounced the same way?

Comment: Type the terms separately into YouTube and hear for yourself

Comment: no, but green **piece** is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are "whores" and "horse" homophones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273/are-whores-and-horse-homophones)

Comment: Actually, I guess technically it is not an exact duplicate, since the answers there don't address the matter of stress. KarlG was right to point that out. But I am not going to retract my close vote because I feel this question in its current form would have to be closed anyway for other reasons if it wasn't closed as a duplicate. If you can, please edit to explain what research you have done, and why you were still confused after researching this topic.

Answer (score 1):

> Greenpeace
>
> green peas

are not pronounced the same. *[Peace](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peace?s=t)* is pronounced /pis/ (unvoiced s-sound) and rhymes with *fleece, crease,* and *cease*, while *[peas](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peas?s=t)* is pronounced /piz/ (voiced z-sound) and rhymes with *fleas, ease*, and *breeze*. Further, *Greenpeace* only carries a stress on the first syllable (like *mouthpiece*), while in *green peas*, *green* has a secondary stress and *peas* a primary stress (like *blue seas*).