# The /z/ sound at the end of a word

Tags: phonology

ESL students, whose L1 is Spanish, have a hard time paying attention to the /z/ sound, especially in end position: **please**, **eyes**, **surprise**. Learners assume that what sounds at the end is the /s/ sound.

When the /z/ sound is at the beginning or in mid-position, the are likely to hear it: **zero** or **result**.
What's the reason for this? Is there a phonological concept shedding light on this?

Comment: ESL of what language? Not all language learners have this problem. One explanation could be that the ESL learners you're used to don't have /z/ at the end of words

Comment: @Mitch ESL stands for *English as a second language*.

Comment: @Alejandro, yes, but what is their first language? Mitch is suggesting (reasonably) that the students first language affects whether they will have this issue.

Comment: Also this question might be a better fit on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @The Photon yes, I edited my post.

Comment: Voiced sounds often get devoiced when they're at the end but I don't know the reason.

Comment: I _think_ the best place to ask this is on LanguageLearning.SE; it's not totally about the English language (as it does not ask about difficulties native speakers face). Nor, as Mitch says, does it involve all other languages.

Comment: [10 Pronunciation Mistakes Spanish Speakers Make](https://youtu.be/cwk24w8Qsy8?t=226). Spanish does not have /z/ (voiced version of 's'). So it is natural to pronounce 's' instead. Also, in many languages, and across all languages when a child is learning it, there is a tendency to devoice word-final sounds.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are "whores" and "horse" homophones?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273/are-whores-and-horse-homophones)