# What do we use ‘Ms.’ or ‘Mrs.’ when we write about a person whose marital status we don’t know?

Tags: word-choice, prefixes, grammatical-gender, feminine

Also, What if we have a general idea about the the marital status of a person. Especially, in the case of ‘Mrs.’, if we seem to have a good idea about the marital status of a woman, can we write ‘Mrs.’ ? Would it be alright the other way (if we refer to them as ‘Ms.’). If we don’t know about girls’ marital status, would it be rude to refer them as ‘Mrs.’, or ‘Ms.’ is fine either way ?

Answer (score 2):

While *Mrs.* is used only for married women, and *Miss* is used only for unmarried women, *Ms.* is used for women regardless of marital status, as [Grammarly explains.](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/ms-mrs-miss-difference/) As [Wikipedia explains,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms.#Usage) different style guides have different opinions on the matter, but some hold that one should use *Ms.* for all women who do not specifically prefer *Mrs.* or *Miss.*

Note that *Ms.* and *Miss* are pronounced differently. As [Cambridge notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ms?q=Ms.), *Ms.* is pronounced with a /z/ at the end, whereas *Miss* has an /s/ sound. (If you're not a native speaker, though, [this might not sound the way you'd expect.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273/are-whores-and-horse-homophones/342281#342281))

Comment: OT: in British English we don't place a period after such abbreviations. It is 'Ms' and 'Mrs' and for a physician 'Dr' all without a period. The period is used when the abbreviation does not keep the first and last letter, such as with 'etc.' (*etcetera*).