'wins' versus 'winds' versus 'wince' verus "wintce" Intrusive /t/ before devoicing in final position
According to J. Higgins, the wins/wince contrast is not so much between /z - s/ as between a fully voiced vs partially devoiced /ɪn/.
I wonder if, once the citation form wins shows devoicing of the /z/ before silence, an intrusive /t/ might appear as it usually does in wince.
Secondly, I wonder if the devoicing of /z/ would also make winds a (near)homophone of wince.

Not to mention winds to go with wins/wince. There are lots of these sets: tens/tends/tense/tents, pens/pends/pents/pence, glance/glands/glans, bunce/bunds/bunts, fence/fends/fens/fents, fines/finds, quince/Quinn's/quints, wince/winds/wins, expands/expanse, stance/stands, dens/dense/dents, lance/lands/LANs, mince/mints, pence/pends/pens/pents, sends/sense, sins/since, hands/Hans, etc.

The proper term for this t sound is "epenthetic t"; "intrusive t" appears to be a misnomer (https://roa.rutgers.edu/files/637-0104/637-HALL-2-0.PDF).

Possibly relevant to the last sentence of your question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/342273/

Possibly related: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11.

I'm afraid that, whilst well-meaning, that website is not quite up to scratch (and its marketing is very misleading).
When a syllable ends with a voiceless consonant—what we call in the trade a fortis consonant—the preceding vowel (and any other sonorant consonants, for example nasal sounds like /m/ or /n/) are shortened, or 'clipped'. So, for example, you will be able to hear that the vowel in bead is longer than the clipped vowel in beat (try it!). We call this process pre-fortis clipping.
The chief auditory difference between wins /wɪnz/ and wince/wɪns/ has nothing to do with any imaginary "devoicing" of the /ɪn/ segment, but rather, the shortening of the sononorant /ɪn/ section of the syllable in wince due to the process of prefortis clipping.
Precisely because of the neutralisation of the contrast between /s/ and /z/  caused by final obstruent devoicing, it is the radically differing lengths of the vowels in winds and wince  which makes the two words distinguishable. This same contrast is retained whether or not there is an epenthetic /t/ or /d/ before the sibilant.
So, in short, there is a fairly robust contrast between pairs like wins and wince, or bead and beat and so forth - and it has nothing to do with the devoicing of any vowels.
There are minimal pairs in English which are distinguished primarily by the devoicing of vowels. However, this differentiates voiced and unvoiced plosives at the beginning of certain syllables.
For example, the words peak, /pi:k/, and beak, /bi:k/,  both begin with bilabial plosives, notionally distinguished by voicing. However, if said in isolation, the initial /b/ in beak will become devoiced, because it will be occurring after silence. However, the words are clearly distinguishable because the initial /p/ in peak will cause aspiration, a little /h/-like sound heard after the release of the /p/. This /h/-like sound is actually the devoiced section of the following vowel.
That's all folks!
