# How to pronounce the "s" of pupils

Tags: phonetics

How to pronounce the "s" at the end of pupils. What is the phonetic of this 
word.

Comment: The same as "apples".

Comment: It's a phonemic /z/. Sometimes native speakers might pronounce it in ways that sound more like /s/ to speakers of other languages (i.e., it's not always fully voiced), but if you pronounce it as a /z/ you should be understood perfectly. And if you pronounce it like an /s/ you may not be.

Comment: @Peter I have to disagree there—if you pronounce it [s], you’ll be understood just fine. That goes for pretty much all plural /z/’s: there’s so much variation and vacillation in the [z] → [s] direction, even within native speakers, that non-native speakers using the unvoiced allophone where the voiced would be expected is _extremely_ unlikely to cause any kind of problems in comprehension. In the majority of cases, it would probably not even be noticed.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, using [s] will cause prefortis-clipping, which will be the major factor in distinguishing *pens* and *pense* or *peas* and *peace*. So, using [s], will be problematic in several instances, though maybe not in *pupils*. (The other factors distinguishing [s] and devoiced [z] are not entriely insignificant. The increase in air pressure for [s] is much greater, whether voiced or not, and [s] is therefore appreciaby louder, all other things being equal, than devoiced [z]).

Comment: @Araucaria In a _native speaker_, yes, pre-fortis clipping will usually occur; in many non-native speakers (which the asker here appears to be), that won’t necessarily be the case. The vowel distinction between [pʰiˑs] and [pʰiːz] is essential to native speakers, but lost on many non-native speakers. And of course there are many instances where pre-fortis clipping accompanies sublevel devoicing, but not surface-level devoicing, even in native speakers, so you end up with unvoiced [s] with no clipping.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, you end up with devoiced [z] with no clipping! ;)

Comment: @Araucaria Meh, same difference. At least, I personally have yet to see any convincing evidence that there’s any significant perceptual difference between [s] and [z̬]…

Comment: See also [Does “fathers” in RP exclude R and unvoice the S?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29132)

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, Peter Shor wrote:

> It's a phonemic /z/. Sometimes native speakers might pronounce it in ways that sound more like /s/ to speakers of other languages (i.e., it's not always fully voiced), but if you pronounce it as a /z/ you should be understood perfectly. And if you pronounce it like an /s/ you may not be.